# Access 2010 After Update SendEmail Command

Tags: ms-access

I currently have a database to send an email if a table (column) is updated and product storage reach low levels. I got all that working fine. However, on the send email action I had some questions.

Is there a way to make responses customaly generated?

For example the Administrators email is in another table and product names could be attached to the emails response?

I had tried to use expressions (with help) from the builder but I was having no success.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The VBA code that you use to create and send the email messsage can do any number of things to customize it. For example, to retrieve the name and email address of a different recipient based on some condition, you could use code like this:

```
Select Case productType
    Case "bacon"
        adminName = "Gord"
        adminEmail = DLookup("email", "tblAdminInfo", "adminName=""" & adminName & """")
    Case Else
        adminName = "(generic admin)"
        adminEmail = "admin@example.com"
End Select
```

Similarly, you could customize the body of the email message by doing something like this:

```
emailBody = ""
emailBody = emailBody & "Hey " & adminName & "," & vbCrLf
emailBody = emailBody & vbCrLf
emailBody = emailBody & "OMG, we're running low on " & productType & "!" & vbCrLf
emailBody = emailBody & vbCrLf
emailBody = emailBody & "Product details for " & productType & ":" & vbCrLf
emailBody = emailBody & DLookup("description", "tblProductDetails", "productType=""" * productType & """") & vbCrLf
```

Try using a couple of techniques like these, and if you run into any difficulties then create a new question with your specific issue.